# Class declaration problems

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

so I've been teaching myself the new ES6 syntax and I put together a small example to practice the new features. Now I've had a really weird error coming from this code:

```
class bird { 
  var actions = ["run","jump","fly", "chirp"]; 
  let actionValue = 11;
  preformActions(){
    actions.map((action) => {
      console.log(action);  
    });
  }
}
let birdy = new bird();
birdy.preformActions();
```

the problem is that on the first line of the class's statement block jslint is giving me a error stating 'unexpected token'.

is there a problem with the way I declared this? this seems like a very easy problem to fix but what am i missing?

Comment: `class` doesn't define a `function`. remove `var` and `let`.

Comment: Yes, there is a problem with the way you declared that. The body of a class isn’t a list of statements, so `var` and `let` don’t belong. What you can have are functions, like p**er**formActions(), and accessors, like `get foo() { return bar; }`.

Comment: And there should be a constructor… ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll want to have instance properties that are initialised in your constructor. A `class` body must not contain `var` or `let` declarations.

```
class Bird { 
  constructor() {
    this.actions = ["run","jump","fly", "chirp"]; 
    this.actionValue = 11;
  }
  performActions(){
    for (const action of this.actions)
      console.log(action);
  }
}
let birdy = new Bird();
birdy.performActions();
```

Of course, *inside* those methods you can have local `let`/`const`/`var` etc variables.